# How to deploy a SSR React App in Azure App Services?

Tags: reactjs, azure, azure-web-app-service, server-side-rendering

I setup a simple application using [razzle](https://github.com/jaredpalmer/razzle) and React. It works perfectly on my local machine, even production build. When I try to deploy the app to Azure I encounter error 500. I checked the logs and the app is indeed started, but the  server is is never reached ('/' route).

I tried this [web.config](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Using-a-custom-web.config-for-Node-apps) file and tested it with a simple Express app and it works great, but it doesn't work for me.

This is my server.js

```
const server = express();
 server
   .disable('x-powered-by')
   .use(express.static(process.env.RAZZLE_PUBLIC_DIR))
   .get('/*', (req, res) => {
    console.log("This should trigger")
```

And this is index.js

```
import http from 'http';

let app = require('./server').default;

const server = http.createServer(app);

let currentApp = app;

server.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, error => {
  if (error) {
    console.log(error);
   }

   console.log(' started in port ', process.env.PORT || 3000);
 });
```

This code compiles into a single server.js file (which I already point in my web.config file)

I check the logs and this line appears in the logs

```
console.log(' started in port ', process.env.PORT || 3000);
```

But not this one

```
console.log("This should trigger")
```

Neither any content or response from the server.

Hope you could help. This is driving me nuts.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to follow the README of GitHub repo [`jaredpalmer/razzle`](https://github.com/jaredpalmer/razzle) to build and run the simple project `my-app`, then discovered the command `npm run build` will compile the value of the code `process.env.PORT || 3000` of `src/index.js` into `build/server.js` as the figure below.

[image]

Note: if I set `PORT` environment port with value `5000` via command `set PORT=5000` on Windows or `export PORT=5000` on Linux, the port `"3000"` above in `build/server.js` will be instead of `"5000"`, not `process.env.PORT` code.

However, to run a Node.js app on Azure WebApp, you have to use `process.env.PORT` to read the port from environment variable `PORT`, then to upload all files within `build` and the `web.config` file onto Azure to make the app using the value of `PORT` environment variable set by WebApp to work.

So to fix this issue, you need to manually replace `"3000"` with `process.env.PORT` via search `"3000"` or the value of `PORT` environment, as the figure below, then to do the deployment.

[image]

Comment: @CarlosOrtiz Any update? Could you mark my answer if it helps?